# loop error when numbers entered

Tags: c++

why this loop executes 3 times when a number is entered? I only want 's' or 'm' to be accepted.. how could I fix this?

```
cout << "Are you married or single (m/s): ";
    cin >> status;
    status = tolower(status); //converting to lower case

    //validating imput for marital status
    while((status != 'm') && (status != 's'))
    {
         cout << "Sorry, you must enter \"m\" or \"s\" \n"
              << "Are you married or single (m/s): ";
         cin >> status;
         status = tolower(status);
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your variable `status` is probably declared as:

```
char status;
```

So, `cin >> status` reads a *single* character from the input. However, you probably typed more than one because the input is buffered and you needed to press Enter.

Instead, use this declaration:

```
string status;
```

which will get the whole line of input, and then you can inspect the characters within the line.

Comment: You should explain that 3 is probably because of "a\r\n"

Comment: `\r\n` should be automatically translated to `\n` by the stream (I suppose that `cin` is automatically in text mode)...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getchar()` to save into status,
it reads only one character from buffer..

```
    cout << "Are you married or single (m/s): ";
    getchar(status);

    //validating imput for marital status
    while((status != 'm') || (status != 's'))    //status can be a male OR a female
    {
         cout << "Sorry, you must enter \"m\" or \"s\" \n"
              << "Are you married or single (m/s): ";
    getchar(status);
    }
```